# why are const variables not stored in the symbol table when compiling object files?

Tags: c++

c++ beginner here. I have a program with lots of globals shared across many .cpp source files (I've been given this to refactor from a single huge file, and need to do so quickly, rather than make it best practices). My idea is to write a header file that uses `extern` to declare all these globals, which I include wherever needed, and then have a .cpp file where they are all initialised. e.g.

```
extern int a;
```

in the header file and

```
int a = 1;
```

in the .cpp file.

This generally seems to work, except for anything using `const`. In this case the variables initialised in the .cpp do not end up in the symbol table when compiled (i.e. I can't find the variable when grepping through for it in the .o file), and I get a linking error saying undefined reference to variable. Why is this? Is it a language thing, or a compiler thing? (I was given a pretty sizeable makefile which I'm unfortunately not able to fully understand)

Comment: @PaulR I'm not positive either, but the *"I get a linking error saying undefined reference to variable"* tipped me off that it is likely the same issue.

Comment: In this case, const implies internal linkage in C++, which is likely why it's not shown in your object symbol tables.

Comment: Are you remembering to declare the variables `const` in the .cpp file as well?  I use `extern const` all the time in this kind of situation without problem.